# PHP Regex: group must end with character but do not capture this character

Tags: php, regex

Example regex:

```
/^([\w]+:)?other:(.*)$/
```

Example string:

```
test:other:words...
```

The first group would match "test:", but I want it to only capture "test". At first I thought:

```
/^([\w]+)?:?other:(.*)$/
```

But I realised I can't have a single *:* in the beginning. How can I capture a group which if exists must end with *:* but this *:* MUST NOT be captured by the group?

Example input and output:

```
randomString:constantString:somethingElse
```

should give 'randomString' as first group.

And

```
constantString:somethingElse
```

should give the first group as empty

Comment: I don't know the whole situation you have, but maybe this is easier to get all what comes before the first ':' `^([^:]+)` =)

Comment: @Enissay, no. This random string cannot be made of any characters, just the ones I need.

Comment: Non capturing or non-consuming match?

Comment: Yeah, things are clearer when you added an example... remember to always add one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we go:

```
^(?:(\w+):)?constantString:(.*)$
```

(?:) is a non capturing group

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/tB9oL1)

Answer (score 2):

If you want your first word to be optional, use:

```
/^(?:(\w+):)?other:(.*)$/
```

This regex makes `\w+:` as non-capturing group as a whole, and makes it optional. In addition, it also uses a capture group inside to capture `\w+` part.

So, if `\w+:` is there, the group 1 contains `\w+` part, else it contains an empty string.

Comment: But I need the first group to be optional.

Comment: @Dalius. It would be better if you can post some sample input, and output. It's hard to understand what you actually want.

Comment: Not sure which answer should I mark as accepted. Both are the same, but the one I currently marked was first :?

Comment: @Dalius. Don't worry about that. You can accept which ever answer you like.